# read line by line awk and if

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a File called contenido.txt
the file have inside the next table

```
Nombre column1 column2 valor3
Marcos    1      0     0
Jose      1      0     0
Andres    0      0     0
Oscar     1      0     0
Pablo     0      0     0
```

I need a final file or a print of the lines that only has 0 in the column2

could you help me please?

```
cat contenido.txt | while read LINE; do
var=$(cat $LINE | awk '{print $2}')

if ["$var" == 0]
then
echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'
fi
done
```

Comment: Do you need to use awk for this? I'd say grep is enough...

Comment: fedorqui. just the second column, that is column1.

Comment: danstahr, can you help me using only grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your codes, the `column 2` you meant is actually the 2nd column( the column with header "column1"), it is not the column with header "column2". So this line will help you:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next}$2==0' file
```

test with your data

```
kent$  echo "Nombre column1 column2 valor3
Marcos    1      0     0
Jose      1      0     0
Andres    0      0     0
Oscar     1      0     0
Pablo     0      0     0"|awk 'NR==1{print;next}$2==0'
Nombre column1 column2 valor3
Andres    0      0     0
Pablo     0      0     0
```

and the 2nd part of your codes seem that extracting the first column (names?) out. You can do this in one shot with awk (ignore the header):

```
kent$  echo "Nombre column1 column2 valor3
Marcos    1      0     0
Jose      1      0     0
Andres    0      0     0
Oscar     1      0     0
Pablo     0      0     0"|awk '$2==0{print $1}'      
Andres
Pablo
```

Comment: hi Kent, could you please give me all the structure of the sentence. I don't know where I have to put |awk 'NR==1{print;next}$2==0' , I will be very grateful.

Comment: @user2838528 step1, remove all your codes, step2: put this line in your script (if you have to have a script file): `awk 'NR==1{print;next}$2==0' contenido.txt` it will print the whole lines, if you want only the name, like the 2nd part in my answer, you just do `awk '$2==0{print $1}' contenido.txt`.

Comment: kent! I want to thank your answer! I can not give you reputation because I am starting in this site! but very very thanks.

Comment: @user2838528 no problem, but I think you can mark the answer as accepted answer. if it solved your problem. there is a tick below the down/up vote number. if you cannot do that either, no problem either, happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`column2` is `$3` in awk. So:

```
$ awk '$3 == 0' < in.txt
Marcos    1      0     0
Jose      1      0     0
Andres    0      0     0
Oscar     1      0     0
Pablo     0      0     0
```

`{print $0}` is the implicit action.

Comment: There is no need to `< file`, `awk 'command' file` is more than enough. Also, to check if the 3rd field is empty or not it would suffice `awk '!$3' file`.

Comment: I like to think in pipes, that's why I use `<`. I don't see that the OP wants to test for empty.

Comment: Mispelled, `empty` --> `0`.